# type error concatenation, but doing int addition in variables

Tags: python, concatenation

Here's the code, but it says `TYPEERROR: Can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`. How do I fix this?

```
if x + grid > len(maze):
    print("Invalid Move.")
```

The values of grid is calculated as `grid = level + 2`
where `level` is an input number from 1-3.
In the above program, `x` is the position of the user in the list (index).

Comment: The error says you Can ONLY concatenate string to a string. So, you can convert to a string your x: `str(x)`.

Comment: @luis he needs to do math operations with numbers so he doesn't need string

Comment: He is comparing against the `len(maze)`. You can not use the len function in a number.

Comment: Which are the types of `x`, `grid` and `maze` (int, float, str...)? What do you intend to do with the plus (`+`) operator, sum or concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

Inputs in Python are saved as strings.  When you take the input for level, try wrapping it like this:

```
level = int(input())
```

This will convert it from a string to an int and you should be able to perform addition on it.

Comment: ah, i've done that, but the error is still there :(

Comment: @secretlymaia Are you sure all the relevant variables (`level` and `x`) are int? Can you check it by adding `print(type(level))` and `print(type(x))`?

Comment: Also, double check what line number it is giving when it throws the error so you can be sure of which variables are the problematic ones.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, yes all of them are in int.

Comment: Then, as dptaylor suggested, check the error message to verify that the error is actually happening in that line of code. I can't reproduce it using ints for `x` and `grid` and a list for `maze`.

Answer (score 0):

function `input()` turns any user's input into `str` 
even if user's input a number it will be turned into `str` 
so to solve your problem you need to just wrap user's input into `int()` to make it integer

Answer (score 0):

```
if int(x) + int(grid) > len(maze):
    print("Invalid Move.")
```

Notes:
Check your bind key to variable x, does it assigning x to int or str.